# unable to start kafka server/broker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

when starting the kafka broker i am getting some error:
I am giving last few lines of the error log:

```
INFO zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected) (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2016-05-12 01:07:01,759] INFO Log directory '/var/logs/service-bridge-logs' not found, creating it. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-05-12 01:07:01,778] INFO Loading logs. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-05-12 01:07:01,796] INFO Logs loading complete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-05-12 01:07:01,797] INFO Starting log cleanup with a period of 300000 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-05-12 01:07:01,806] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-05-12 01:07:01,874] INFO Awaiting socket connections on gns3-d.cloudapp.net:9092. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
[2016-05-12 01:07:01,875] INFO [Socket Server on Broker 2], Started (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2016-05-12 01:07:02,042] INFO Will not load MX4J, mx4j-tools.jar is not in the classpath (kafka.utils.Mx4jLoader$)
[2016-05-12 01:07:02,168] INFO 2 successfully elected as leader (kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector)
[2016-05-12 01:07:02,386] INFO Registered broker 2 at path /brokers/ids/2 with address 10.1.0.4:9092. (kafka.utils.ZkUtils$)
[2016-05-12 01:07:02,416] INFO [Kafka Server 2], started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2016-05-12 01:07:02,529] INFO New leader is 2 (kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$LeaderChangeListener)
[2016-05-12 01:07:25,798] ERROR Closing socket for /40.122.64.23 because of error (kafka.network.Processor)
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
at kafka.utils.Utils$.read(Utils.scala:380)
at kafka.network.BoundedByteBufferReceive.readFrom(BoundedByteBufferReceive.scala:54)
at kafka.network.Processor.read(SocketServer.scala:444)
at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:340)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

while in zookeeper sidealso am getting few error:

```
INFO Established session 0x154a35b64f40000 with negotiated timeout 6000 for client /10.1.0.4:36673 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2016-05-12 01:07:02,313] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x154a35b64f40000 type:delete cxid:0x1d zxid:0x52 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/admin/preferred_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2016-05-12 01:08:33,001] INFO Expiring session 0x154a35b64f40000, timeout of 6000ms exceeded (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2016-05-12 01:08:33,001] INFO Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x154a35b64f40000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2016-05-12 01:08:33,017] INFO Closed socket connection for client /10.1.0.4:36673 which had sessionid 0x154a35b64f40000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
```

Any idea guys??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you see log line `INFO [Kafka Server 2], started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)` says your Kafka Server already started. Regarding error, it is just warn message and it doesn't do anything with Kafka Server. you can find more info here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2251

Comment: yes just after the servers starts, i get this error!! no clue why!!

Comment: It's not `ERROR` its just `WARN` message. You will get that message when consumer closes connection. Please go through the link I shared in previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user [avr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5936696/avr) pointed out, this is a known bug in Kafka 0.8.2.x
These are routine informational messages misclassified as `ERROR`.

As of Kafka v0.9.0.0, the loglevel has been corrected to `WARN`.